# Consulta con session::flash en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, phpmyadmin

Mi consulta es sobre como tratar esta clase de errores.

Hasta el momento sé que esto sucede porque no se puede borrar un registro que dependa de otro registro de otra tabla, el cual están relacionados.

Pero mi pregunta si se puede mostrar otra clase de error, algún mensaje, o una ventana diferente a la común cuando aparece esta clase de errores.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pensaba en lograrlo con `Session::flash()` dentro de la función `destroy()` de mi controlador, en donde muestre un mensaje de error, en vez de pasar a esa ventana. Pero no se como hacerlo muy bien. Gracias.

Información adicional:

De esta manera tengo realizado el código en donde trato de establecer un mensaje de error.

```
public function destroy($id){

  try {

    $autos = AutosNew::find($id);

    $autos->delete();

    Session::flash('message', 'Automóvil eliminado correctamente del registro');
    return redirect()->back();

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return "Fatal error -" .$e->getMessage(); 
  }
}
```

Y si falla el `destroy()` quisiera mostrar un mensaje de error, en lugar del error que muestra la imagen que coloqué.

Comment: Me da la sensación que tienes el entorno en modo desarrollo, y por eso te sale la pantalla de control de errores. Prueba a cambiar de entorno y configura tus plantillas el error

Comment: La idea es mostrar otro error y evitar que mande a la base de datos el destroy(), mi idea es que muestre un error diferente a esa pantalla confusa para el usuario. Por eso decía si hay alguna forma de hacerlo con Session::flash() Uso un try{} catch(), aunque el error ese lo hice a propósito es solo que me preguntaba si se podía mostrar una pantalla diferente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que no estás usando bien try...catch, creo que tu código debería verse más o menos así:

```php
public function destroy($id){

  $autos = AutosNew::find($id);

  try {

    $autos->delete();

  } catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {

    Session::flash('message', 'El automóvil no se pudo eliminar correctamente del registro');
    return redirect()->back_o_donde_sea();

  }

  Session::flash('message', 'Automóvil eliminado correctamente del registro');

  return redirect()->back();


}
```

Aunque tu código esté en el bloque del "try", cuando se produce el error al intentar eliminar el registro, lo inmediatamente siguiente deja de ejecutarse y el cursor salta directamente al bloque del "catch"; es precisamente ahí donde debes decidir que harás con el error.

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero al momento de aplicar aquello, no funcionó, mi sitio sigue mostrando el mismo mensaje que aparece en la imagen que publiqué.

Comment: Lo cierto es que el código era más una indicación... para acercarte más, cambia la línea del catch por:

"} catch ( Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {"...

Lo actualizo en la respuesta.

Comment: Ya veo, acabo de aplicar aquello, pero sigue igual, quizás no es posible poner un mensaje de error o alguna otra ventana.

Comment: Añade una barra invertida al principio de la excepción: "\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e"... vuelvo a editar la respuesta.

Comment: Gracias era lo que buscaba, aparece el mensaje que esperaba, además me gustaría saber si es posible, cambiar el color del mensaje, aparece de color verde, si es posible dejarlo en rojo, por ejemplo. ¿Como lo debería hacer?

Comment: No hay de qué... eso es otro tema totalmente distinto y otra pregunta; pero la solución la tienes en el código HTML y CSS